# Porter Stemmer and Weka

Tags: java, weka, snowball

I am using Weka with the porter Stemmer provided in the SnowBall package. Everything works fine if I run my application within Eclipse, but as soon as I export it as runnable jar (With all the libraries included) weka says:

```
Stemmer 'porter' unknown!
```

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 4):

The Snowball jar is not in your classpath, as described in [the wiki](http://weka.wikispaces.com/The+snowball+stemmers+don%27t+work,+what+am+I+doing+wrong%3F). When you run your jar, you need to make sure the Snowball jar is in your classpath. You could also unpack the Snowball jar and include it in your project.